# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python, ntlm, www-authenticate

My requirement is to download an abc.zip file from some website http://clientdownload.xyz.com/Documents/abc.zip

For this activity I have written a python script as follows:

```
    url_to_check = 'http://clientdownload.xyz.com/Documents/abc.zip'
    username = "user"
    password = "pwd"
    p = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    p.add_password(None, url_to_check, username, password)
    handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    zip_file = urllib2.urlopen(url_to_check).read()       
    file_name = 'somefile.zip'
    meta = zip_file.info()
    file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
    print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)

    with open(file_name, 'wb') as dwn_file:
        dwn_file.write(zip_file.read())
```

Whereas I am getting the following errors when I run the script:

> File "updateCheck.py", line 68, in check_update
>       zip_file = urllib2.urlopen(url_to_check).read()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
>       return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
>       response = meth(req, response)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
>       'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
>       return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
>       raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

I have given the user name and password properly but it throws unauthorized error.

When I tried to download it using wget link with `-http-user and --ask-password` options, I am able to download the file.

Also using the same script I am able to download files from other servers properly.

I ran this script to get more info:

```
import urllib2, re, time, sys

theurl='http://clientdownload.xxx.com/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx'

req = urllib2.Request(theurl)

try:
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)

except IOError, e:

    if hasattr(e, 'code'):

        if e.code != 401:
            print 'We got another error'
            print e.code
        else:
            print e.headers
            print e.headers['www-authenticate']
```

I got the following information:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 939bad00-40b7-49b9-bbbc-99d0267a1004
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.6029
Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 13:14:19 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 16
```

NTLM

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're using a basic auth handler with a NTLM authentication. Try with something [like this](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/).

Comment: Yeah, Already tried using the Ntlm Auth Handler whereas my python installtion doesnt have NTLM package so I got the following error.
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

Comment: Well, you could install the package or use a [virtual environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). virtualenv is part of python best practices (afaik) and allows you to install custom stuff without messing your original python installation.

Comment: Have you ever got a solution to this? I am also seeing similar import errors.
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement     HTTPNtlmAuthHandler (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to make it easier to interact via HTTP. In your case by installing [`requests-ntlm`](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm/) (a plugin for `requests`) you will get [NTLM authentication](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm/blob/master/README.rst) in a more transparent way:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

r = requests.get("http://ntlm_protected_site.com",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))
```

`r` holds the response, including [error codes](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) and [headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-headers) (specifically for your case `r.headers.get('Content-Length')[0]`)